# How to get the number of records on every unique date?

Tags: pandas, time-series

`ts` is a time series, which has a data type as `pandas.core.series.Series`, `ts.index` has data type -`pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex`, I want to know the number of records on every specific date. So far, I get it via below

```
unique_date = ts.index.map(lambda t: t.date()).unique()   
for item in unique_date:
    print(ts[ts.index.date == item].shape[0])
```

I guess there is a better way in pandas.

---

Beside of `ts.index.normalize().value_counts()`, seems like `ts.groupby(ts.index.date).count()` is also an available way. What the difference on the performance between these two approach?

Comment: `ts.index.normalize().value_counts()` ?

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks. That's what I exactly want.